# session not identified

Tags: php, mysql

i've created a session but after entering the email & password in "login.php" the page is again redirected to "login.php". the following code is the next page to the "login.php" that checks for the validation of email & password.

```
<?php
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","Rahul","");

    if (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }

    mysql_select_db("ebusiness", $con);
    $result=mysql_query("select * from members where Email='$_POST[login]' and Password='$_POST[pwd]' ") or die(mysql_error());

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
        if(strcmp("trim($_POST[login])","trim($row[Email])"==0 ) && strcmp("trim($_POST[pwd])","trim($row[Password])")==0) {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.5;url=home.php'/>";
            session_start();
            $_SESSION['email']=$_POST['login'];
            $_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];
            echo "<br><br><br>";
            echo "<table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#F0F0F0'><tr></tr><tr align='center'><td><h3>Please wait...</td></tr></table>";
            return;
        }
    }
    mysql_close($con);
?>
```

and the "home.php" page is the page that shows the information upon successfull validation.
code for home.php:

```
 <?php
   session_start();

    if (!isset($_SESSION['email'])) {
        header("Location: login.php");
        return;
   } else {
        $con = mysql_connect("localhost","Rahul","");
        mysql_select_db("ebusiness", $con);
        $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM members WHERE id = $_SESSION[id]") or die(mysql_error());

        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            echo "<table height=100% width=100% border='0' cellspacing='0'><tr height=20%><td colspan=2>";
            include 'header.php';
            echo "</td></tr>";
        }
   }
?>
```

the session is first created on the "welcome.php" and on "home.php" it checks whether a session exists or not. and then it redirect to the "login.php". But as i've created a session already.. i dont understand why the home.php is not loading. plz help me..

Comment: Put session_start(); to top of every page. And what is this line ? if(strcmp("trim($_POST[login])","trim($row[Email])"==0 ) && strcmp("trim($_POST[pwd])","trim($row[Password])")==0) <--parse error, so it wont work

Comment: @iiro the line that you mentioned is working perfect.. there is no issue on that... because i have run it before creating sessions. and even after creating the session, it worked fine for few times.. but now its not working

Answer (score 0):

Try

**Login.php**

```
<?php
    ob_start();
    session_start();
    $con = mysql_connect("localhost","Rahul","")or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db("ebusiness", $con)or die(mysql_error());;

    $result = mysql_query("select * from members where Email = '".$_POST['login']."' and Password = '".$_POST['pwd']."' LIMIT 1") or die(mysql_error());

    if(mysql_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
        {
            echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.5;url=home.php'/>";
            $_SESSION['email'] = $_POST['login'];
            $_SESSION['id'] = $row['id'];
            echo "<br /><br /><br />";
            echo "<table align='center' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0' bgcolor='#F0F0F0'><tr></tr><tr align='center'><td><h3>Please wait...</td></tr></table>";
            return;
        }
    }

    mysql_close($con);
    flush();
?>
```

Comment: in your query you are getting result which are equal to email and password so no need to reacheck it using strcmp...now all you need to do is just check if query return more than 0 record and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

Put

> session_start();

top of every page. But, what you see below is not an answer to your question. Check this line:

```
if(strcmp("trim($_POST[login])","trim($row[Email])"==0 ) && strcmp("trim($_POST[pwd])","trim($row[Password])")==0)
{
```

look at this `strcmp("trim($_POST[login])","trim($row[Email])"==0 )` 
which means

```
strcmp("sometext","someothertext"==0 )
```

which means

```
strcmp("sometext",true)
```

so your line

```
if(strcmp("trim($_POST[login])","trim($row[Email])"==0 ) && strcmp("trim($_POST[pwd])","trim($row[Password])")==0)
    {
```

is same as

```
if(true && strcmp("evenmoretext","evenevenevenmoremoretext")==0)
    {
```

which is

```
if(true && 0==0)
```

which is

```
if(true && true)
```

So you reach this `echo "<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.5;url=home.php'/>";` because `When a string is specified in double quotes or with heredoc,` **variables** `are parsed within it.` But no **functions** (trims, in this case) are parsed!

Some tests:

```
$_POST['login'] = 'postemail';
$_POST['pwd'] = 'posttest';
$row['Email'] = 'postemail';
$row['Password'] = 'posttest';

var_dump("trim($_POST[login])"); // string(15) "trim(postemail)"
var_dump("trim($row[Email])"); // string(15) "trim(postemail)"
var_dump("trim($row[Email])"==0); // bool(true)
var_dump(strcmp("trim($_POST[login])","trim($row[Email])"==0 )); //int(1)
```

In my opinion, you should clear and fix your code. For example the first if-statement should be:

```
if(strcmp(trim($_POST["login]"),trim($row["Email"]))==0 && strcmp(trim($_POST["pwd]"),trim($row["Password"]))==0)
```

Comment: i'm reaching the line echo 
"<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0.5;url=home.php'/>"; & the page shows "Please wait..." for a moment and then is redirected to login.php

Comment: @user2078502 oh i see. I edited my answer and you know why you reach that.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `session_start();` in login.php page, Add this at the top of the page.

Comment: i've written it. and its not login.php dats welcome.php .. "login.php" is that file where i am asking the user to input its email and password. and i have not shown dat file here.. after login.php the "welcome.php" executes where the validation process is done.. and at last "home.php" is to be executed.

Comment: `session_start();
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST['login'];
$_SESSION['id']=$row['id'];` remove the `session_start()` from here and place it on top of the page